# Как разрешить доступ к API только от фронтеда(React), находящегося с бэкендом на одном домене с помощью Django Cors на продакшене?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы все хотя бы POST запросы к API были доступны только с сайта на React. Как правильно настроить cors? Или какую технологию и как использовать?

Django Rest работает с помощью gunicorn + nginx,при указание в url /api/ nginx проводит прокси с gunicorn:

```
location /api/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        proxy_redirect default;
    
}
```

настройки Django сейчас имеет такие:

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'домен'
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://домен",
    "http://домен",
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://домен",
]
```

Comment: Если они на одном домене, то просто вообще убрать настройки cors и с любых других доменов доступа не будет

Comment: @AlexeyTen, убрал, перезагрузил сокеты и сервисы gunicorn, но не помогло. Я через POSTMAN проверяю, отправляю с него POST запрос

Comment: Ну так постман не смотрит не cors. О него только csrf и авторизация

Comment: @AlexeyTen, если даже POSTMAN может обойти корсы, то какой метод можете посоветовать мне использовать? Мне необходимо защитить API от спама POST запросами с разных источников таких как POSTMAN и другие, чтобы POST запросы принимались только с фронтенда размещенного на нкшем домене

Comment: «Если алмазным сверлом можно взломать мой сейф, то зачем сейф?» CORS не для защиты от спама. Для защиты от спама нужно ограничивать запросы и банить настырных. Например fail2ban или отдать это на откуп специалистам (cloudflare, hostguard и т.п.)

Comment: Авторизация на jwt токенах. Боюсь ничего лучше пока не придумали

Comment: Фраза «запросы с домена» лично для меня (и думаю для большинства остальных) подразумевает запросы из браузера. Потому что всё остальное это «запросы с сервера» и CORS тут вообще ни при чём.

Comment: @Talleyran, А если разместить бэк и фронт на  разных доменах, то можно будет решить проблему через cors?

Comment: Постману всё равно где у вас фронт